# Turn lights are blinking at a different rate

Tags: electrical

I am rewriring my car with new harness and I noticed something strange. My left turn lights blink faster than my right turn lights. They are both routed through the same relay and I don't think they did that with the old harness.

- 1959 Nash Metropolitan
- Positive Ground
- No after-market electronics remaining (It has a radio and temp guage, but I removed them because the wiring was done incorrectly.)

Answer (score 4):

If it's not a problem in the wiring, it could simply be different rated bulbs.  Try swapping the bulbs from the left to the right (front & back) and see if that affects the rate.

Answer (score 3):

There is a wire somewhere grounded. The system works in old cars by heating an elements that separates, and joins once cool again. If you updated, the newer stuff uses a relay that would mimics this in a way. Look for the light that is either out or dim, and then chase the wires.